# Pro Pain - Down For The Cause - Help to understand the song

Tags: lyrics

[Link to lyrics](http://www.lyricsdepot.com/pro-pain/down-for-the-cause.html).

I guess only fans from the time recognize the question but all the same I'm asking it.

Knowing that the band is from the 90s, and from New York.
Not being from USA and was teen when they were one of the heard of around the world.

What was the theme of their lirycs and which "subculture" was that in NYC at that time.

I am just curious to feel all the variety of people that we are one part of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the time period (2002), this is a clear reference to the then recent terrorist attack that leveled the World Trade Towers in NYC (usually referred to as 9/11, referring to the day in 2001 when it happened).

> I cried a thousand times for those who lost their lives up in NYC
>   Friends underneath remains from such a dirty game
>   Looks like world war 3
>   Picking up the pieces while we try to make some sense of it all - can we?
>   Dont't you try to underscore the nature of it all with your sympathy

You wouldn't need to be a part of a New York subculture to have resonated with these lyrics at that time.  It was a seismic event across the United States, and had a global impact.  However, given that they were based in New York, it's possible that they literally had friends who perished in the attack.